# iPhone music app tab bar icons

Tags: iphone, icons

I'm after the tab bar icons found in the native music app found on iOS. I have tried looking through the glyphs but couldn't find anything. Didn't have much luck on google either. Even tried the looking through iTunes resources but could only find 2 of them and they are too small. I was under the impression they were found in Xcode but couldn't find them in there either.

Comment: http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/iphone-4-gui-psd-retina-display/ This link has iPhone GUI PSD file. Maybe it can help you find that icon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're going to have to start cutting them out manually in Photoshop. Good Luck!

[image]